# How to select a range of cells until a specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a row with 100+ cells that have certain values.

I need to select all of those rows, until a specific value appears (lets say its the string "STOP").

Currently I have the following code that basically just lets me select everything until the last cell with a value in it.

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
```

But, I need the selection to not go all the way to the end but right before the cell with "STOP" in it.

Answer (score 0):

Trying looking across the row to find *STOP* and the column that defines the *column_num* argument of the second Cells..

```
Range(Selection.Cells(1), Cells(Selection.Cells(1).Row, Application.Match("stop", Selection.Cells(1).EntireRow, 0)-1)).Select
```

I'm using `Selection.Cells(1)` because Selection could be more than one cell in more than one row and this will only work on a single row.

You might also want to start writing code without using Select and Selection.

Comment: Thank you, my high quality sir. That worked perfectly.